# Why does my C program do not jump out the while loop even when the exit condition is met

Tags: c, loops

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    int value;
    int smallest = INT_MAX;

    printf("This is a program that finds out the minimum \nof serveral integers you entered.");
    printf("Please type in these integers: ");

    while(scanf("%d", &value) != EOF)
    {
        printf(" ");

        if(value <= smallest)
        {
            smallest = value;
            printf("%d", smallest);    // to trace the while loop
        }
    }
    printf("\nThe smallest integer is: %d", smallest);    // this will execute once the program is stopped
    return 0;
}
```

This code can find the smallest integer successfully, but just doesn't print the result from

```
printf("\nThe smallest integer is: %d", smallest);
```

.. until I stop the program from my C intepreter. I don't understand why it does not print immediately, since there are no more iterations in the `while` loop.

Comment: Try adding a `\n` at the end of the last `printf`

Comment: How do you input the values and send the EOF?

Comment: EOF is the End Of File, you don't use files. You need a different `while` condition.

Comment: @boh, wrong, _if a reading error happens or the end-of-file is reached while reading, the proper indicator is set (feof or ferror). And, if either happens before any data could be successfully read, EOF is returned._

Comment: @CoolGuy It is still the same :(

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen the user enter the input from keyboard

Comment: @StephenPan , And after entering numbers, how do you send `EOF` to end the loop?

Comment: @CoolGuy I didn't send anything, and I think I did not use the EOF correctly, what I all mean is, to tell the while loop there is no more integer left, all the integers are read.

Comment: "*there is no more integer left, all the integers are read*" -- The program (loop)will wait...wait until further `EOF` is encountered(as you have it in your condition). It doesn't know that you aren't going to enter more numbers. You need to have some kind of indicator to tell the loop to end. As for you code in the question, press CTRL+Z and then enter, if on windows. Else, try CTRL+D. This signalls `EOF`. Otherwise, if you are using @iharob's suggestion `while (scanf("%d", &value) == 1)`, enter a character to end the loop.

Comment: scanf doesn't return EOF at end of file.... it returns 0 as it's trying to read past end of file and no field will be filled with data, see **scanf(3)** for more information.

Answer (score 4):

The better end loop condition, is

```
while (scanf("%d", &value) == 1)
```

which means while [`scanf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) is reading values succesfuly.

Read the link to understand why, when using `scanf()` it's not natural to wait for `EOF` because then the user would have to press a key combination to mark `stdin` with `EOF`.

That key combination is actually so akward that it's not the same for linux terminals <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> and for Windows cmd windows <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd>.

If it does not execute the `printf()` statement, it's because you need to flush the `stdout`, either add `fflush(stdout)` or add a `'\n'` at the end of every line, it's more natural to add a newline at the end, although I see that many people add it at the beinning.

Comment: On Windows,  `Ctrl-Z` must be followed by ENTER

Comment: it still won't execute the final printf statement after I use while (scanf("%d", &value) == 1)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use EOF like that , because **scanf()** returns value 1 after a successful read.**scanf()** wont return the character it read. I have given solution below, I think it works as you wanted.For any queries comment below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    int value;
    int smallest = INT_MAX;

    printf("This is a program that finds out the minimum \nof serveral integers you entered.");
    printf("Please type in these integers (Enter any other character to terminate): ");
    while(scanf("%d", &value))
    {


        if(value <= smallest)
        {
            smallest = value;
            printf("smallest till now: %d\n", smallest);    // to trace the while loop
        }
        else
            printf("smallest till now: %d\n", smallest);    // to trace the while loop

     }  
     printf("\nThe smallest integer is: %d\n", smallest);    // this will execute once the program is stopped
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the solution, I also have done similiar to this and it works now.